# find own function position in json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, function, position

how can i "navigate" in `Json` or find out where (related position) the function in the json.

Something like "this" in a `HTML DOM` for Json.
How can i navigate there like "parent", "children"?

A code out of the Json is not nice, because the json functions move there positions and get added and removed.

pseudo Json Code

```
test = {"test1":{function(){return this[a]+this[b]+this.c()+this.children['bla']},a:12,b:344,c:{function(){return this[a]},a:33 }},"bla":" is the value"}
```

Thanks

PS: the DOM is too slow and should run on node.js/io.js

Comment: That's not JSON.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: please explain your goal.

Comment: `indexOf` is what you're looking for?

Comment: the goal is a multiple self changing code. So there is no "this" of a function in a Json?

Comment: yes something like indexOf, but from the function it self in a complex Json tree with a lot branches (really a lot)

Comment: found JSONfn, but there is "this" only the full Json object and not the position in the Json. Looks like the only solution is to track all the way up in the tree. That makes it slow again, like the DOM. Anybody an idea?